# asp.net mvc area Routes stopped Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have had a working project for months now....This week I decided to change some of my areas....I deleted two areas and created a new Area...

After doing this I can't add any new controllers to the existing areas and get them to route correctly.   I am seeing other strange things....for instance I am not getting autocompletion of the services path....It only list the controllers within the areas and not the models or the services....

I have created new controllers in the new areas...and these worked fine.....but something is messed up in the "old" areas....

I am not sure where to start looking for this.....in some ways it sounds like a routing issue...but the routes did not change....so I think it might be a configuration issue.... but which configuration file....each area has its own configuration file and then we have the master configuration file....

Has anyone see a problem like this?

Comment: where are you not getting autocompletion ?

Comment: What kind of changes did you make to your areas?  Can you show the `AreaRegistration` of the area's you're having issues with?

Comment: when I am typing (using visual studio 2012...

Comment: For an area of Vehicle and a Controller of Dealer It is working to do ProjectName.xxxx.Vehicle.Dealer .... but it used to work to do Vehicle.Dealer.ModuleName and this is no longer working....  There are places in the code where this is and there is NO complaint about this...but trying to insert new code it does not find it.... which is very similar to what is happening with the controller so I am thinking this is a problem with the configuration and not the routes....

Comment: Here is the arearegistration

Comment: using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EtracsWeb.Areas.Vehicle
{
    public class VehicleAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Vehicle";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Vehicle_default",
                "Vehicle/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Vehicle/ServiceRequest/List

Comment: Have you tried "Clean build" and rebuilt it? might be "old dll" files getting published to your server. Do you have MVC istalled on your local machine? Might need to install it using platform installer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to debug your routes.

Comment: Thanks...I will keep this in mind for the future....but see below, the answer turned out not to be a route issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer....At the same time that I changed the areas I renamed the project.... When I created the new areas they got the namespace created using the OLD project name....and I did not notice the namespace was wrong.... The clue to this was the fact that path completions were not working....I should have looked more closely at this....

Now the big question, and the reason that I am marking this as the answer is....where does the project name get retained in asp.net mvc..... I have looked in the web.config and I have done a global search for the old project name ..... Any clues where to change this???